# Implementing JK Flipflop in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to implement simple `JK Flipflop` in Verilog (Modelsim). But I'm getting the following error

> The generate if condition must be a constant expression.

Here is the code which I'm using

```
module jkfflop(J,K,clk,Q);
input J,K,clk;
output Q;
 if(J==0 & K==1)
  begin
   assign Q = 0;
  end
 else if(J==1 & K==0)
  begin
   assign Q = 1;
  end
 else if(J==1 & K==1)
  begin
   assign Q = ~Q;
  end
endmodule
```

Can someone help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing Sequential Circuit in Verilog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421318/implementing-sequential-circuit-in-verilog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Verilog RTL there is a formula or patten used to imply a flip-flop. for a Positive edge triggered flip-flop it is `always @(posedge clock)` for negative edge triggered flip-flops it would be always @(negedge clock).

An Example of positive edge triggered block.

```
 reg [7:0] a;
 always @(posedge clock) begin
   a <= b;
 end
```

Normally you want a reset as well, a **Synchronous** reset would be:

```
 reg [7:0] a;
 always @(posedge clock) begin
   if ( reset == 1'b1 ) begin
     a <= 'b0; 
   end
   else begin
     a <= b;
   end
 end
```

It is more common is ASIC design to require an active low **Asynchronous** :

```
 reg [7:0] a;
 always @(posedge clock, negedge reset_n) begin
   if ( reset_n == 1'b0 ) begin
     a <= 'b0; 
   end
   else begin
     a <= b;
   end
 end
```

Note that the asynchronous reset has reset in the sensitivity list this makes the block respond to changes in the signal.

The way you have used (reused) assign is incorrect.

Using the above info your module would become:

```
module jkfflop(
  input  J,
  input  K,
  input  clk,
  output Q );
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(J==1'b0 && K==1'b1) begin
      Q <= 'b0;
    end
    else if(J==1'b1 && K==1'b0) begin
      Q <= 1'b1;
    end
    else if(J==1'b1 & K==1'b1) begin
      Q <= ~Q;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

But could be written with a case statement:

```
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    case({J,K})
      2'b0_0 : Q <= Q   ;
      2'b0_1 : Q <= 1'b0;
      2'b1_0 : Q <= 1'b1;
      2'b1_1 : Q <= ~Q  ;
    endcase
  end
```

Comment: `module flopJK(q,j,k,c);
     input j,k,c;
     output q;
     reg q;
     always @(posedge c)
     begin
      case ({j,k})
       {1'b0,1'b0}:begin q=q; end
       {1'b0,1'b1}:begin q=1'b0; end
       {1'b1, 1'b0}:begin q=1'b1; end
       {1'b1, 1'b1}:begin q=~q; end
      endcase
     end
    endmodule`

Comment: kindly fix the last module(can't edit)
->          2'b0_1 : Q <= 1'b0;
->          2'b1_0 : Q <= 1'b1;