# Implementing Sequential Circuit in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to implement the following `Sequential Circuit` in `Verilog` (Modelsim 10.4a)

[image]

Here's the code I'm using

**seq_circuit1.v**

```
module seq_circuit1(x, clk, Q0, Q1);
 input x, clk;
 output Q0, Q1;
 reg J0,K0,J1,K1;
always @(negedge clk)
begin
 //Blocking and Non Blocking both will work
 J0 = Q1 & ~x;
 K0 = Q1 & x;
 J1 = x;
 K1 = (Q0 & x) || (~Q0 & ~x);
 jkfflop JKff0 (J0,K0,Q0);
 jkfflop JKff1 (J1,K1,Q1);
end
endmodule
```

**jkfflop.v**

```
module jkfflop(J,K,clk,Q);
input J,K,clk;
output Q;
 if(J==0 & K==1)
  begin
   assign Q = 0;
  end
 else if(J==1 & K==0)
  begin
   assign Q = 1;
  end
 else if(J==1 & K==1)
  begin
   assign Q = ~Q;
  end
endmodule
```

I'm getting some errors and I'm unable to figure out why. Can anybody tell me where did I do it wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**seq_circuit1**

- You can't instantiate submodules (your FFs) inside an `always` block.
  Move them outside, either before or after.
- Your instantiations for `jkfflop` are missing the `clk` input signal.
- based on your diagram, your inputs to the FFs should be combinational logic, not sequential, and should therefore use an `always @(*)` block, not a clocked one.

**jkfflop**

- `if` statements in verilog are only valid inside a `generate`, `always` or `inital` block. Since this is a FF, you'll want an `always @(posedge clk)` or `always @(negedge clk)`
- If using an always block, replace the `assign` statements with non-blocking assignments (`<=`). We use NBA's here instead of a blocking assignments (`=`), as it's an edge-triggered block.
- If assigning a value to `Q` inside an always block, change `output Q` to `output reg Q`